# Proprietary Realtek Wireless Driver not available on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 a few days ago after Windows just became too boring. But I had one problem where my Wi-Fi connection was pretty slow and I had no problems with my network before. I searched the internet and most of the sources said I should install my drivers. I checked what my wireless adapter was by using:

```
lspci |grep "Network controller"
```

It gave the output 'Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter' so I searched the internet to install the specific drivers and I found something.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms

sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

The second command gave me a package not found error and another source said I should enable the **multiverse** and **universe** APT repositories and try again but to no avail. Then I checked the https://packages.ubuntu.com website and searched the package name but it just showed that the package was available for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. What should I do to install the drivers? Nothing shows up on **Additional Drivers**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it still helps: this [site](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/kablosuz/+index) has `rtl8821ce-dkms` for kinetic, i.e. Ubuntu 22.10.

How to install via ppa should work for your kinetic as did beatifully for [my jammy](https://fostips.com/realtek-wifi-drivers-ubuntu-linux-mint/). Don't forget to blacklist:

```shell
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add

```
blacklist rtw88_8821ce
```

at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Just for those not familiar with nano: of course, afterwards, you have to save and exit: "<Ctrl>+<O>, <Enter>, <Ctrl>+<X>, reboot"